# couchbase I am doing to set index on the right place?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am puttin the index on the right place ?

I want to index from a document the product_id.

```
CREATE INDEX `index_product_id` ON `products` (product_id) USING GSI;
```

I want to index this field: (product_id)

```
{
  "**product_id**": "32132",
  "rating": 5,
  "id": "554f500b-912c-43f1-8caa-eea54b8301ff",
  "_type": "products_rating"
}
```

Comment: It's a little confusing because in your example document, there's a field named `**product_id**`. I assume you meant to bold/highlight that field? If so, then, yes, you are creating an index on the `product_id` field with that `CREATE INDEX` statement. Whether or not that's the "right" index is a whole different question, and depends on your querie(s).